# Some cities producing 2 for 1 units

Tags: civilization-6

My cities have produced 2 for 1 units. Aircraft carriers, destroyers and modern armour. A few times.

I have looked around and cannot work out how this can be happening.

Perhaps it is the civics? +100% production. but then again, there is 50% production.

Maybe this is a bug.

Playing emperor difficulty. Have harbour and encampment districts and many cities.

Comment: Do you have any wonders? I know the Venetian one lets you get 2 for 1 on naval units.

Comment: Shame on me i thought this was a bug and reported it to 2K (while i mentioned this might be due to some wonder). However this gives you also a nice boost for gold since you could sell the extra unit. However i had a bug with carriers. The second one couldn't handle planes properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Venetian arsenal in one of my not-so-unit-producing cities.

Since the civopedia is incomplete and vague I thought I would add this answer.

The Venetian Arsenal empowers **any** city building a naval unit to produce 2.

Untested, but if true; A powerful wonder if building armada level units!

Comment: This is indeed correct. It is a powerfull wonder on maps with alot of Ocean. http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Venetian_Arsenal_%28Civ6%29